# regexp: filter a character in an expression but not inside the quotation mark

Tags: java, regex

Suppose I have an expression `a?.foo("xyz?abc")`, I want to use regexp to get rid of `?` at `a?.foo` but not the one inside `"xyz?abc"`, what should I do?

Note I am using Java

Comment: What about unmatched quotes? Can one escape quotes?

Comment: an escaped quotes will have be put inside an outer quotes, so it shouldn't be an issue. Unmatched quotes is an error and should not be considered here. However it needs to consider cases that there are multiple quotes pairs, e.g. `a?.foo("xyz?abc").bar("123?456")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must capture content inside double quotes first, example:

```
String subject = "a?.foo(\"x\\\"yz?abc\").bar(\"123?456\")";
String regex = "(?s)(\"(?>[^\\\\\"]++|\\\\{2}|\\\\.)*\")|\\?";
String result = subject.replaceAll(regex, "$1");
```

Comment: awesome! I guess I should switch to this one

Answer (score 1):

```
    System.out.println("a?.foo(\"xyz?abc\")"
        .replaceAll("(\".*?\"|\\?)", "$1§")
        .replaceAll("\\??§", ""));
```

I either replace the char or a string "..." with a special unused char `§`,
and then remove the `§` together with an optional char.

Comment: Nice solution, thx a lot. only concern is on the performance side. But anyway I am gonna use this one for the moment

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using the `appendReplacement` functionality of a `Matcher`.

Basically we search for `"(notQuestionMark)?(notQuote)"` and replace it with `"(notQuestionMark)(notQuote)"`

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {   
    final String[] ss = {"a?.foo(\"xyz?abc\")", "a?.foo(\"xyz?abc\").bar(\"123?456\")"};
    final Pattern patt = Pattern.compile("(\"[^?]*+)\\?([^\"]*+\")");
    for(final String in : ss) {
        final Matcher m = patt.matcher(in);
        final StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        while(m.find()) {
            m.appendReplacement(sb, "$1$2");
        }            
        m.appendTail(sb);
        System.out.println(sb.toString());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
a?.foo("xyzabc")
a?.foo("xyzabc").bar("123456")
```

This might be faster than an approach that uses two `replaceAll` calls as you can reuse the `Matcher` using `Matcher.reset(String s)` and the actual search and replace is only done once.

Reusing the `Matcher` would look something like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {   
    final String[] ss = {"a?.foo(\"xyz?abc\")", "a?.foo(\"xyz?abc\").bar(\"123?456\")"};
    final Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(\"[^?]*+)\\?([^\"]*+\")").matcher("");
    for(final String in : ss) {
        m.reset(in);
        final StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        while(m.find()) {
            m.appendReplacement(sb, "$1$2");
        }            
        m.appendTail(sb);
        System.out.println(sb.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds great, but I still love Casimir's answer because of it's simple style. But I give you an up anyway. Thanks Boris!

Comment: @green You're right, that solution is much neater - didn't think of capturing the while pattern from a lookahead.

Answer (score 0):

```
String s = "a?.foo(\"xyz?abc\")";
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("(a\\?\\.)", "a."));
```

but i suppose this is not what you are asking, right?

Comment: No, `a` shouldn't exists in the solution, it's just an example